# Como Popular uma Listview, e dela Popular outra Listview pela Primary Key?

Tags: c#, listview, wpf, algoritmo-de-busca, linq-to-sql

Tenho duas ListViews que preciso popular utilizando LINQ to SQL (C#, projeto em WPF) de um campo de pesquisa. Ao digitar no campo(textbox) o evento KeyDown irá popular a primeira ListView (1), como a segunda possui uma coluna que é a Primary Key da primeira, preciso que nessa segunda ListView (2) busque as Primary Key populadas na primeira ListView (1). É possível?

Detalhe: Em ambas as listas as variáveis são strings porém possuem valores distintos. Por exemplo, na ListiView(1) se pesquisa uma Descrição e na ListView(2) uma Primary Key que são números (apesar de ser uma string) que está na ListView(1) também.

Entenda: DataBases_1 Popula ListView_1 
         DataBases_2 Popula ListView_2

```
DataBases_1
Codigo(string_PK) | Descricao (string)
101               | Uva 
202               | Maca
303               | Melao
404               | Salada Mista
505               | Morango

DataBases_2
Nome              | Codigo(string_PK) 
Joao              | 404
Maria             | 404
Paulo             | 505
Felipe            | 101
Renata            | 202
```

**Método de Pesquisa da Primeira ListView(1) - Evento KeyDown :**

```
using (DataClassesDataContext oDB = DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var busca = from p in oDB.DataBases where p.Descricao.Contains(txtPesquisa.Text) orderby p.Codigo descending select p;
    listView_1.ItemsSource = busca.ToList();
    listView_2.ItemsSource = ??????? ---> //Popular com base na lista encontrada pelo ListView_1 (var busca)
}
```

XMAL:

```
       <ListView x:Name="listView_1" Margin="34,345,618,51" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" SelectionMode="Extended"><ListView.View>                                                                  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Código" Width="Auto"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Codigo/>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Descricao" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Descricao}"/>
            </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

        <ListView x:Name="listView_2" Margin="1050,345,72,51" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListView.View>     

        <GridView>
<GridViewColumn Header="Nome" Width="Auto"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nome}"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Código" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Codigo}"/>
            </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma segunda busca usando os códigos da primeira busca:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext oDB = DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var busca = from p in oDB.DataBases_1 where p.Descricao.Contains(txtPesquisa.Text) orderby p.Codigo descending select p;
    listView_1.ItemsSource = busca.ToList();
    var codigosList1 = busca.Select((b) => b.Codigo).ToList();
    var busca2 = from p2 in oDB.DataBases_2 where codigosList1.Contains(p2.Codigo) orderby p2.Codigo descending select p2;
    listView_2.ItemsSource = busca2.ToList();
}
```

Recomendo colocar a busca da segunda listview no event onchange (ou equivalente do WPF) da primeira list view.

Comment: Opa...Daniel as ListViews consultam o banco pela ferramenta LINK to SQL. Dessa forma não está correta a expressão listView_1.SelectedItems[0].Codigo ....Consegue arrumar?

Comment: Retirei a listview da chamada Linq. Tente agora

Comment: Daniel...Não deu certo...A ListView precisa ser populada pelo método LINQ..Também não achei a função OnChange nos eventos...Projeto é em WPF.

Comment: Mas qual o erro que dá?

Comment: Só poderei ver hoje às 20h30 (horário de Brasília)...Consegue ficar online essa hora? Assim poderemos trocar uma ideia melhor no bate-papo daqui...Pode ser?

Comment: Até o momento nem roda porque o SelectedItems[0].Codigo não é reconhecido...

Comment: Daniel, deu parcialmente certo...Porque a ideia é ao digitar na textbox os dados do primeiro Banco apareçam na primeira ListView, e dessa pesquisa os Codigos populados na primeira ListView busquem os dados semelhantes no segundo Banco para popular a Segunda ListView...Esse método só pode pesquisar por um único código...O que quero precisa pegar mais de um código pesquisado e popular esses códigos semelhantes na segunda ListView...Entende?

Comment: Por exemplo...Pode ser que o usário na textbox pesquisa pela palavra "Ma" nesse caso será populada: Maca, Melao e Morango; Códigos 202, 303 e 505. Nesse caso precisa popular esses códigos na Segunda Listview...

Comment: Em breve...Verifico sua atualização Daniel!

Comment: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value...Esse foi o erro...Tem a ver com o fato de ter alguma coluna com Datas?

Comment: Show, Daniel!! Muito obrigado!!